# The embedding $W^{2,2} (\Omega)\hookrightarrow L^\infty(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded set with regular boundary.

Under which condition on $n$ is the embedding $W^{2,2}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow L^\infty(\Omega)$
continuous?

Comment: By the Sobolev embedding this is true if $4>n$. For $n\geq 4$ we don't even have the inclusion as sets.

Comment: And if we have the inclusion as sets, it is automatically continuous by the closed graph theorem.